Crash on WinDbg remote debugging of gdbserver on 32 bit elf
I am trying to use gdbserver in WSL to debug programs with Windbg, but getting a crash of the dbgserver with the following output:
Process ./program created; pid = 454
Listening on port 1234
Remote debugging from host 172.24.64.1, port 61926
readchar: Connection reset by peer
Segmentation fault

The debugging works with other binaries, such as cat, but not with my program.
I suspect this is because the program is a 32-bit elf and windbg does not support this, but can't find any evidence of this in windbg's documentation or anywhere else.

You are incorrect, see the  documentation in Microsoft’s website, which says it is generally supported - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/linux-live-remote-process-debugging

Then, which version of WinDbg do you use? If you have an old version, you may need to install the 32 bit version and 64 bit version individually and use the correct one. New versions should auto-detect. https://aka.ms/windbg Don't use the "Preview" version any more.
